# Statistical test over binary data

Tags: statistical-significance, binary-data

Given certain products (ProductA, ProductB, ProductC, etc..) users are asked to rank them according to their preference (whether they like, somewhat like, or not like, the product).

Thereafter I have extracted certain binary features from these products (handle is present or not, etc..) and now I want to test which features are prominent (statistically significant) in user liked, somewhat liked and not liked products.

What sort of a statistical test I should use for this sort of a problem and why?

---

Edit: I have posted a partial analysis in the form of a fitted model below as an answer, but I have some followup questions:

According to the link in my answer, since the 95% CI does not cross 0, all the parameter estimates are statistically significant.

1. What does it mean by "parameter estimates are statistically significant"?
2. How can interpret the change happen in the outcome if one of the variable changed given that all the other variables are stationary?
3. How do you interpret any relationships among the binary features from this results?

Comment: I'd consider logistic regression; it models the probability of a binary response in terms of predictors (which can be anything numerical, so 0-1 variables are fine). There are other possibilities (it's basically a classification problem), but logistic regression would be my first instinct.

Comment: could you please give me some idea about how I can use logistic regression in such a scenario.

Comment: Actually, I think I was misled by your title; while your predictors are binary, the part that matters in terms of figuring out what procedure is required - the response - is not binary, but ordinal. You might do that with ordinal logistic regression, for example.

Comment: @Suranjith [Here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/ologit.htm) is a good tutorial on how to perform ordinal logistic regression.

Comment: Glen_B, COOLSerdash appreciate your feedback. Thank You

Comment: Suranjith - neither of us saw your reply. If you want someone's attention you need to write an @ in front of their username, like @COOLSerdash -- that will signal them that you have replied to them. Only one such @ works in a comment though. It's not necessary to do this if you reply to an answer (the answerer gets signalled with every response under that answer) or a question (the person asking the question is signalled with every response in their question).

Comment: My understanding of what you are trying to do is take user ratings for products A, B, C… and then figure out which product features in a fixed set of features have a significant impact on the user ratings. It might be interesting to consider the interaction effects between the individual features.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the suggestions proposed by Glen_b and COOLSerdash I did an ordinal logistic regression using 375 instances each comprised of 10 binary features and the results are as follows.

```
 values   |std error| T-Value |    P-Value  |  2.5% | 97.5% |
-3.40728  |  0.0750 | -45.4461|       0     | -3.55 | -3.26 |
-2.61808  |  0.0590 | -44.3806|       0     | -2.73 | -2.50 |
-2.03321  |  0.0519 | -39.1592|       0     | -2.13 | -1.93 |
-1.71011  |  0.0493 | -34.7131|    4.99E-264| -1.81 | -1.61 |
-1.37915  |  0.0472 | -29.1895|    2.63E-187| -1.47 | -1.29 |
-1.17436  |  0.0463 | -25.3652|    6.11E-142| -1.27 | -1.08 |
-0.94292  |  0.0455 | -20.7434|    1.41E-95 | -1.03 | -0.85 |
-0.78121  |  0.0450 | -17.3608|    1.64E-67 | -0.87 | -0.69 |
-0.66665  |  0.0447 | -14.9029|    3.16E-50 | -0.75 | -0.58 |
```

According to [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/ologit.htm), since the 95% CI does not cross 0, all the parameter estimates are statistically significant.

I have some followup questions which I will put in my question.

Comment: results were calculated using mnrfit in Matlab passing model as ordinal and I assume returned results are in log odds scale.

Comment: Please don't ask questions in answers! While your output might be regarded as a partial answer to your question, your followup questions don't belong; they should go in your question or be posted as a new question. I will move them to the end of your question, but if you wish to post a new question (with a link to this one) you can delete them from there and post them as a new question.